# Exclude logging from function

Tags: c++, logging

I've encountered this problem multiple times. Is there a "smart" way to exclude logging from functions? Especially if there is a logical check (if/else) before the logging happens. I would like to have this if/else excluded too. For example:

```
Return_Value = Init_Winsock();

if( Return_Value != 0 )
{
    cout << "(" << __FILENAME__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "): ";
    Errorcode_To_String( __FUNCTION__ );
}

else
{
    cout << "(" << __FILENAME__ << ":" << __LINE__ 
    << "): " << "INFO: winsocked started" << endl;
}

Socket = socket(    AF_INET, 
                    SOCK_DGRAM, 
                    0 );

if( Socket == INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    cout << "(" << __FILENAME__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "): ";
    Errorcode_To_String( __FUNCTION__ );
}

else
{
    cout << "(" << __FILENAME__ << ":" << __LINE__ 
    << "): INFO: UDP socket opened" << endl;
}
```

I would like to have the two if/else in a seperate function, preferably in one. Is something like this possible in c++? Maybe even a seperate logging class that should be as neatly as possible?

Comment: please post something approximating what you would want -- even if it's not valid c++ to give people a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

the logging lines have to be places where you want to log. There is no way around this.

That said, usually it is a good idea to have logging macros that can be de-activated when in production, [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-lightweight-logger-for-c/240147505) explains how to do it (with complete code)